# solr export handler export to xml instead of json

Tags: solr, export, handler

I am trying to figure out if there is any way we can export all the data in solr collection to a large file.

looks like we can do this :- 
[Exporting Result Sets](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Exporting+Result+Sets)

what if I want to export the data in XML file instead of JSON?

I tried `wt=xml`  ...which as expected did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once the `/export` request handler is defined, you can use it to make requests to export the result set of a query. All queries **must include** `sort` and `fl` parameters, or the query will return an error. Filter queries are also supported. **Results are always returned in JSON format.**

Looks like that is not supported in the solr.

As you have not mentioned any specific requirement other than extracting the data. You can use the `/select` API and get the data in `XML` format.

A simple query like this will do that job:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/coreName/select?q=*%3A*&wt=xml&indent=true
```

You can use the `fl` parameter if you are looking for only sub set of fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't in the condition to modify the `solrconfig.xml` and you want export part or the entire collection in a json simple format, well, there is an alternative.

I wrote a java tool: https://github.com/freedev/solr-import-export-json

This is a java application that exports a Solr collection using `SolrJ`.